# Searching a pdf file from multiple files using java

Tags: java

We want to fetch only particular pdf files from  multiple pdf files in a folder using java code it must be web view.please kindly help me...

```
package manju1;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manju1
{
     public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
     { 
          File  location= new File("c:\\testpdf\\");
          String type = ".pdf"; // replace what ever type of file you need to search

          if (location.isDirectory() && location != null) 
          {
             for (File f : location.listFiles()) 
             {
                if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) 
                {
                    //System.out.println(f.getName());
                    System.out.println("enter the first string");
                    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
                    String m=in.nextLine();

                    if(m.equals(f.getName()))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Strings are equal");
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:\\testpdf\\swathi.pdf");
                        System.out.println("This PDF has "+reader.getNumberOfPages()+" pages.");
                        String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,1);
                        System.out.println("Page Content:\n\n"+page+"\n\n");


                       break;

                    }                                                
                    else 
                    {
                       System.out.println("Strings are not equal");  
                    }                                                

                 }
            }
        }
  }
```

This program stores the files by default in order and checks the entered string if both matches then displays it otherwise its not displaying. We want a code to fetch the pdf file when we enter from the keyboard not in order. If file we search is present in that folder it should display it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this.  What is the above code doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: Please improve the code formatting and title as well.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find a file in a particular directory, the name of which is supplied by the user?

Instead of searching all of the files, you could do the following:

```
    File location= new File("c:\\testpdf\\");
    String type = "pdf";
    if (location != null && location.isDirectory()){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = sc.nextLine();
        File file = new File(location, fileName);
        if(file.exists() && FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath()).equals(type)){
            //The file exists
        }
        else{
            //the file doesnt exist
        }

    }
}
```

Id like to note that I do
`if (location != null && location.isDirectory())` instead of the other way around, so that, if location is null, you wont get an NullPointerException

Let me know if I have misunderstood, or this was unclear

Comment: Hi, Thank you somuch for  your  help.but I am getting an error in this below mentioned line.if(file.exists() && FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath()).equals(type)).especially in FilenameUtils.getExtension. kindly help me in sorting  the problem.but the requirement i need you have understood very well Thanks for that.I hope you will reply me soon.